# Can I use jquery.js directly in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jquery, nullpointerexception, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I already have a simple application, to experiment I am implementing the same in Struts 2. In an old app I've used jQuery, now can I use directly the same `jquery.js` here or shall I opt for Struts 2 jQuery Plugin?

I tried with `jquery.js`, I am getting null pointer exception. So I am confused now. Some one tell the difference between two. Both are jQuery only wright?

Comment: Which to use depends on a number of factors. Either are usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `loadAtOnce` in `<sj:header>` tag to `true` to disable on demand script loading. So the `jQuery` script will be loaded at page load. You should be able to use your own library scripts without manually loading your own copy of `jquery.js`.

[Ref. Here](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/HeadTag)

Answer (score 1):

If you have got `NullPointerException`, it doesn't mean that JQuery or [plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=119537#content/view/119537) has bugs. You are getting errors because you are doing something wrong in the code, misunderstanding or something.

Struts 2 JQuery is a tag library that you can use with Struts 2 framework. It contains the JQuery inside it. JQuery is only a JavaScript library. Using the plugin you have Ajax support with Struts 2 framework.